# Mission control keyboard shortcuts: add more desktops

Tags: keyboard, shortcut, desktop, mission-control

I've been using i3 window manager on my linux laptop. It's great and I am used to keyboard shortcuts to move to a specific desktop.

On MacOS I have been able to replicate this for the first 3 desktops but I usually have 4 or 5, sometimes up to 9. How could I add a shortcut for those other desktops? I only see an option for the first 3.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will only offer shortcuts for existing, non-Fullscreen, Spaces. If you create a Space it will auto-add a default key command, but not enable it. If you create & destroy Spaces, the keys will be removed/switched off each time.* If you use Fullscreen you cannot number their Spaces, so you can only use left/right in Fullscreen.
*I just double-checked that. Custom keys & on/off status *are* retained if you create one, destroy the Space, then re-add it [tested in Mojave].

One additional note - Cmd/[num] is used for switching between tabs in some apps [browsers especially] so may conflict in some cases. Ctrl/num is the default & what it will auto-set each time you create a new Space.
Additionally, if you have an extended keyboard, the numpad & 'qwerty' numbers are recognised separately, but you cannot tell visually from that assignment window. Default keys are for the numbers above qwerty & have to be specifically changed to numpad if you want those.